# parsing nested json keys with jq

Tags: json, filtering, jq

I'm very new at this and I am trying to filter the following nested json key using jq

`

```
{
  "team": {
    "id": "PI6MJXZ",
    "name": "my_team",
    "description": null,
    "type": "team",
    "summary": "my_team",
    "self": "https://someurl.com/my_teams/ID",
    "html_url": "https://someurl.com/my_teams/ID",
    "default_role": "manager",
    "parent": null
  }
}
```

`

However when I run the following jq filter `jq '.team[]'`I get the following output:

`

```
"PI6MJXZ"
"my_team"
null
"team"
"my_team"
"https://someurl.com/my_teams/ID"
"https://someurl.com/my_teams/ID"
"manager"
null
```

`

I know that this is running as intended as I am testing this out on [this jq filter tool](https://jqplay.org/)

My question is, how can I go about filtering one specific key within this nested json key?

What I am looking for using the above example is to output only the following:

`"PI6MJXZ"`

So it should go `team ---> id`

Any help with some explanation as to how one can do this and for a more advanced nested filter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `jq '.team.id'`

Comment: Thanks, this worked out for me. Would you be able to explain or show me a doc which discusses this bit? Would be helpful to learn the mechanics of jq for my future projects and understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, how can I go about filtering one specific key within this nested json key?

Are you trying to [update](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment%3A%7C%3D) `|=` a field (`.team`) by setting it to one of its own fields (`.id`)?

```bash
jq '.team |= .id'
```

```json
{
  "team": "PI6MJXZ"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vmQnLkgXwCf)

Comment: I'm not quite sure if updating a field is what I was looking for, as I am still trying to understand the mechanics of jq. However, this answer has given me a leg up on what I am trying to do. Thanks @pmf and Merry Christmas!